# Растянуть изображение но не больше чем нужно

Tags: html, css

Есть div. У него есть максимальная длина и высота. В этом блоке изображение.

```
<div class="div-img col-md-12 p-0 m-0 center-img">
<img class="img-article" 
 src="http://geniusinfoways.com/common/front/images/bk/img-7.jpg">
 </div>
```

класс

```
.div-img {
 height: 350px;
 background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Класс картинки

```
.img-article{
 max-height: 350px;
 max-width:max-content
 }
```

Нужно что б это изображение автоматически растянулось на весь блок не меняя своего разрешения, что б не осталось левых полей как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но изображение например большое и если я дам ему оригинальный размер  в рамках это блока, то будет виден лишь кусочек картинки во всем блоке. Какие классы применить что б растяжение остановилось на определенном размере и не оставило левых полей? Я понимаю что тогда потеряется какой-то кусочек изображения но это лучше чем растягивать. Нужно как с обложной на фейсбуке.

Comment: [`object-fit: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: где именно добавить єтот класс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div { overflow: hidden; }
img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Отмечу как правильный, та как первый написали, хотя результат с ответом @net22sky не особо отличается. В любом случаи я форматирую изображение для нужной ширины перед сохранением сохраняя пропорции и вот тогда ваши классы делают изображение в точности как на фб

Comment: @FX_Sektor, но лучше использовать `object-fit`.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, чем лучше?

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде `object-fit: cover` не просто обрезает, но ещё и центрирует?

Comment: @diralik, вполне возможно, не уверен. Но на картинке в вопросе центрирования нет.

Answer (score 4):

```
.img-article {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]